# Can you suggest a complete web publish tool except MS Web Deploy?

Tags: sql, asp.net, publishing

I need a web publish tool which can do these.

1. Publish web codes to destination
2. Sql Schema and data compare and save table list which compared.
3. Restart Services With New Codes

Thanks For Your Help.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our current deployment process consists of three things

1. Source Control (Visual Studio Online in our case)
2. [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) which is used to build our .NET web apps
3. [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/) which is used to deploy the built packages from TeamCity

The process is very simple and the majority of the work is automated.

Once code is checked into the master branch, TeamCity will detect the changes and begin our build process which consists of the following steps:

1. Restore NPM packages
2. Run gulp scripts to compile SASS files and minify and bundle JavaScript
3. Build the web app with MSBuild in the release configuration
4. Create a release in Octopus Deploy

This is also done without any work on the developer's side.

The way most of our web apps are setup in Octopus Deploy is the following:

1. Retrieve the packages built from TeamCity(in the form of a nuget package)
2. Deploy the web application performing any Web.config transformations in the process.
3. Deploy any Windows Services using [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) which also performs the needed App.config transformations

When a release is created Octopus Deploy will automatically deploy it to our internal development server so once again no work is required to begin testing the new code. Once everyone is happy we press one more button and it's deployed to all our production servers.

Octopus Deploy has the capability to deploy database schema changes etc too which is covered in this [article](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/SQL+Server+databases), we went with the **change-script-driven** approach in our case.

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you for answering. Secondly, why dont you use TFS instead of TeamCity ?@david-ford

Comment: Mainly because when we set up our deployment process VSO didn't have any build capabilities. I do keep meaning to look into it more but why change something which isn't broken